# Should I capitalize "Chemical Engineering Curriculum"?

Tags: capitalization

> The introduction of this course within the chemical engineering curriculum is at this point in early stages of development.

> The introduction of this course within the Chemical Engineering Curriculum is at this point in early stages of development.

Answer (score 6):

If Chemical Engineering is the name of the department, I would uppercase it.  I would not uppercase "curriculum", though, since this is not a reference to a specific document or the like.  It's just a normal noun, same as "class" or "professor" or "book".

Answer (score 2):

By title, it would be Chemical Engineering curriculum, as it's topically referring to the department/subject. Curriculum is rarely capitalized unless in an abbreviation such as "curriculum vitae" (CV), for example.

Answer (score -2):

Go with:

> The introduction of of this course
>   within the Chemical Engineering
>   Curriculum is at this point in early
>   stages of development.

It looks better capitalized.

Comment: ...and how about "Students in Chemical Engineering are required to..." or "Students in chemical engineering are required to..." ?

Comment: @user8400 I suggest you used lowercase for "students" :)